# Laravel CSRF token empty in AJAX-rendered content

Tags: laravel-5, csrf

"laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
"laravelcollective/html": "^5.4",

I have a view partial that contains delete buttons, and is rendered both normally and through AJAX requests. After the latter, the forms for these buttons are not getting the CSRF token when the partial is rendered. The hidden input value is empty, resulting in a TokenMismatchException when they are subsequently used

**Note that the forms for these buttons DO NOT use AJAX.** My problem has nothing to do with telling javascript to fetch the token from the meta tag and include it in an AJAX request. That works fine. These forms are being submitted with a normal, old-school request. (When the page reloads after delete the content is loaded at the correct page.)

The pagination request that results in the new partial being rendered goes to a controller in API namespace. Thus, i tried adding the "web" middleware to the route in api.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'web']) ...
```

This did cause the token value to show up in the delete forms. However, and as i was pretty sure would happen, it does not match the one that had previously been set in the meta tag.

The token is passed to FormBuilder's constructor. Is there something that i can do in the controller (on the pagination request) to pass the token to View, such that it ends up being passed to FormBuilder before the partial is rendered? (I'm not clear on where/when FormBuilder is instantiated.)

Another idea might be to include the token in the pagination request, pass it from the controller as a view variable, and manually create the token input. (With some logic to only do it for ajax requests.)

That seems hacky, though. I want to think on that a bit further before pursuing it, and was hoping someone might have an idea of how to achieve the former (or a better) solution.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution occurred to me, although it's not specific to Laravel. What I can do is have the pagination component get the token from the meta tag, then check the incoming html fragments for the presence of any _token hidden fields and apply the value as needed.